# "Un grand" vs "le grand": What are the differences? When to use which one?

Tags: articles

They all mean the same I guess. great/wonderful/big but when it comes to french I can't be sure.

e.g: Le Grand Amour / Un Grand Amour (both are used generally if memory serves)

Comment: Be careful with the capitalisation of first person personal pronoun I and not i.

Comment: Actually they don't mean the same. Un grand conveys a great (indefinite article; or one depending on the context) whilst le grand conveys the great (definite article).

Comment: This [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31968/1893) gives some more information about definite vs indefinite articles.

Comment: So, Un Grand is metaphorically "Great" and Le Grand truly "Great" right?

Comment: Alexander the Great is conveyed by Alexandre le Grand. Eddie Van Halen (RIP) was a great guitarist is conveyed by Eddie Van Halen fut/était un grand guitariste. [Sorry if I don't get your question.)

Comment: Could you add more details to clarify your question? I am not sure 100% if I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: If i understand correctly, Eddie Van Halen was a great artist, but subjectively. But Alexander the Great was a great but not as a compliment. He was really "Great" objectively.

Comment: *Grand* doesn't really change its meaning depending on whether it is used with a definite or indefinite article. You can certainly say: *Alexandre le Grand était un grand roi*,  *Van Halen était un grand guitariste* and *Le grand guitariste Eddie Van Halen était aussi un grand admirateur d'Eric Clapton*.

Answer (score 1):

> "Voici un grand chat sur la table." — Here is a big cat on the table.

It is a cat, and it happens to be big.

> "Voici le grand chat dont je vous ai parlé." — Here is the big cat I told you about.

Of all cats, it is specifically the one that is big.